# error when run docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I `docker daemon --api-cors-header="*" -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`(startup the docker), I get this

> WARN[0000] [!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting -tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!]
>
> INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 35410
>
> INFO[0001] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver "aufs"
>
> INFO[0001] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds
>
> WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit
>
> WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs period
>
> WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs quotas
>
> WARN[0001] mountpoint for pids not found
>
> INFO[0001] Loading containers: start.
>
> INFO[0001] Firewalld running: false
>
> INFO[0001] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 
>   172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address
>
> INFO[0001] Loading containers: done.
>
> INFO[0001] Daemon has completed initialization
>
> INFO[0001] Docker daemon                                 commit=8eab29e graphdriver=aufs version=1.12.0
>
> INFO[0001] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock
>
> INFO[0001] API listen on [::]:2375
>
> ERRO[1490] containerd: notify OOM events                 error=cgroup path for memory not found
>
> ERRO[1491] containerd: notify OOM events                 error=cgroup path for memory not found
>
> ERRO[1491] containerd: notify OOM events                 error=cgroup path for memory not found
>
> ERRO[1491] containerd: notify OOM events                 error=cgroup path for memory not found

And then, I check version of docker.

```
root@debian:~# docker -D info
Containers: 4
Running: 4
Paused: 0
Stopped: 0
Images: 3
Server Version: 1.12.0
Storage Driver: aufs
Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Dirs: 20
Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: null bridge host overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options:
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 487.7 MiB
Name: debian
ID: V57N:NOAK:67TQ:PE5F:W3HA:Y2M6:UCRZ:O2OO:UM3Z:WNPM:JKBA:TPGJ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): true
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
```

Is there anyone knowing how to fix it?

Comment: You started docker and connected to it, so which error message are you trying to solve?

Comment: In the yellow block, the last four lines show the error. And I want to solve this.@BMitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The containerd errors should be safe to ignore. They happen with short lived containers and mismatched cgroup paths. A [fix was made to containerd](https://github.com/docker/containerd/issues/188) which I'd expect to be picked up by Docker if they haven't already.

Comment: hi, in my error log, there is `WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit`. I think maybe my kernel doesn't support cgroup but not mismatch cgroup path. I don't know my thought is right. What do you think?

Comment: These are optional features, hence the warning. They allow you to provide additional restrictions on containers. See the [ubuntu install instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/adjust-memory-and-swap-accounting) for how to get rid of these errors (they should also apply to Debian). None of this should prevent you from using Docker.

Comment: Hi, that error has been solved. And my docker works! Thank you very much.

Comment: Btw, are you familiar with hyperledger project? I am new here. And I just get this error `vp2_1  | 05:47:26.676 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 063 Error handling message: Peer FSM cannot handle message (DISC_GET_PEERS) with payload size (0) while in state: created` when I type `docker-compose up`. I just want to build the peer and test fabric.  Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with their project.